# Text from clipboard isn't an array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a small function in my profile to get text from the clipboard:

```
function Get-Clipboard
{
    Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

    PowerShell -NoProfile -STA -Command{
        Add-Type -Assembly PresentationCore
        [Windows.Clipboard]::GetText()
    }
}
```

(Stolen and adapted from http://poshcode.org/2150.)

However, when it captures what's in the clipboard, it doesn't work as I had hoped.

Basically, I want it to replicate the behaviour of the [Get-Content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx) cmdlet, that is, if I have a list in the clipboard like this:

```
COMP1
COMP2
COMP3
```

I would hope that `$comps = Get-Clipboard` would create a simple array of three strings.

I have tried declaring '$comps = @()', which had no effect.

I am sure that this is entirely straightforward, but I've been defeated by my lack of knowledge of the terms required to look this up myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the delimiter you used. For example, if my clipboard text is comp1,comp2,comp3, then you can use:

```
$comps = (Get-Clipboard).Split(",")
```

So, in your case where you have a new-line as delimiter,

```
$comps = (Get-Clipboard).Split("`n")
```